# Queries to Create a Basic Threshold Analysis Report in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my attempt to create a MS Access report for a basic threshold analysis I have created 3 queries that are sequential. The performance is awful given how inefficient they are and I am also not getting the intended results from the final query (explained below). Any suggestions to clean this up would be greatly appreciated.

The first query (Day_Period_Bins_qry1) runs as attended and sums my data into various day period 'bins', which are constructed working backwards from the date entered in a form (Main_frm!Date_prompt_txt). The query (below)  is extremely obtuse, but it is what I got figured out

```
'Category' as N_group, 
Data_tbl.Item_Category as Item, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt] And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-6,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 7Day_Curnt, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-7,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-13,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 7Day_1, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-14,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-20,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 7Day_2, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-21,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-27,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 7Day_3, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-28,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-34,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 7Day_4, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt] And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-27,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 28Day_Curnt, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-28,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-55,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 28Day_1, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-56,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-83,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 28Day_2, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-84,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-111,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 28Day_3, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-112,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-139,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 28Day_4, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt] And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-83,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 84Day_Curnt, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-84,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-167,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 84Day_1, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-168,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-251,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 84Day_2, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-252,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-335,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 84Day_3, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-336,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-419,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 84Day_4, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt] And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-363,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 364Day_Curnt, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-364,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-727,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 364Day_1, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-728,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-1091,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 364Day_2, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-1092,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-1455,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 364Day_3, 
Sum(IIf([Data_tbl].[occ_date]<=DateAdd("d",-1456,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) And [Data_tbl].[occ_date]>=DateAdd("d",-1819,[Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]),1,Null)) AS 364Day_4
FROM Data_tbl
GROUP BY Data_tbl.Item_Category
```

There are two other queries union-ed to the above query that query item_type and item_category.

The second query (Columns_qry2) puts the data from the above query into columns in order for the third column to perform some calculations

```
Select

N_group,
Item,
nz([7Day_Curnt],0) as nCount,
'7Day' as Day_Period,
'Current' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL

Select
N_group, 
Item,
Nz( [7Day_1],0) as nCount,
'7Day' as Day_Period,
'1' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL 

SELECT N_group, 
Item,  
Nz( [7Day_2],0) as nCount,
'7Day' as Day_Period,
'2' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
N_group, 
Item, 
 Nz( [7Day_3],0) as nCount,
'7Day' as Day_Period,
'3' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL 

SELECT N_group, 
Item, 
 Nz( [7Day_4],0) as nCount,
'7Day' as Day_Period,
'4' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

Select

N_group,
Item,
nz([28Day_Curnt],0) as nCount,
'28Day' as Day_Period,
'Current' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
N_group, 
Item,
Nz( [28Day_1],0) as nCount,
'28Day' as Day_Period,
'1' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
N_group, Item,  
Nz( [28Day_2],0) as nCount,
'28Day' as Day_Period,
'2' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

SELECT
 N_group, Item,  
Nz( [28Day_3],0) as  nCount,
'28Day' as Day_Period,
'3' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL

 SELECT 
N_group, Item,
  Nz( [28Day_4],0) as nCount,
'28Day' as Day_Period,
'4' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL

Select

N_group,
Item,
nz([84Day_Curnt],0) as nCount,
'84Day' as Day_Period,
'Current' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


Union All

SELECT 
N_group, 
Item,
Nz( [84Day_1],0) as nCount,
'84Day' as Day_Period,
'1' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL 

SELECT N_group, 
Item, 
 Nz( [84Day_2],0) as nCount,
'84Day' as Day_Period,
'2' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
N_group, Item, 
 Nz( [84Day_3],0) as  nCount,
'84Day' as Day_Period,
'3' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL 
SELECT N_group, 
Item,  Nz( [84Day_4],0) as nCount,
'84Day' as Day_Period,
'4' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL

Select

N_group,
Item,
nz([364Day_Curnt],0) as nCount,
'364Day' as Day_Period,
'Current' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1



Union All

SELECT 
N_group, 
Item,
Nz( [364Day_1],0) as nCount,
'364Day' as Day_Period,
'1' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL 

SELECT N_group, Item, 
 Nz( [364Day_2],0) as Count,
'364Day' as Day_Period,
'2' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
N_group, Item, 
 Nz( [364Day_3],0) as  nCount,
'364Day' as Day_Period,
'3' as Day_bin

FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1


UNION ALL SELECT N_group, Item,  
Nz( [364Day_4],0) as nCount,
'364Day' as Day_Period,
'4' as Day_bin


FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1;
```

The last query is unfinished and in its third or fourth iteration. Currently, I am having problems figuring out how to get the columns to only perform calculations within the same day_period (i.e. calculate only the average for [7day] bins to compare against the current 7day count. Previously, a simple where clause was added (where day_bin = '7day) and repeated in union queries for the other day periods, which would have given me the results I want, but adding one more union query was the log that broke the camels back, causing a crash.

```
SELECT 
Columns_qry2.N_group AS N_group, 
Columns_qry2.item AS Item, 
Columns_qry2.Day_period, 
Columns_qry2.nCount AS Current_Ct, 
Round(Avg(Columns_qry2.[nCount]),2) AS Avg_Prev4_Bins,
 Round((Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_Curnt]-[Avg_Prev4_Bins])/StDevP([nCount]),2) AS Z_score, 
Round((Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_Curnt]-Avg([nCount]))/Avg([nCount]),2) AS PercentChg_From_BinAvg_Prev4Bins, 
Round(Day_Period_Bins_qry1.[7Day_Curnt]/(Select SUM(Day_Period_Bins_qry1.[7Day_Curnt]) FROM Day_Period_Bins_qry1),2) AS Percent_of_Total_Current, 
Round(Avg(Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_1]/(Select SUM(Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_1]) FROM Day_Period_bins_qry1)+Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_2]/(Select SUM(Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_2]) FROM Day_Period_bins_qry1)+Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_3]/(Select SUM(Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_3]) FROM Day_Period_bins_qry1)+Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_4]/(Select SUM(Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_4]) FROM Day_Period_bins_qry1))/4,2) AS Avg_Percent_of_Tot_prev4_Bins, 
Round(([Percent_of_Total_Current]-Avg_Percent_of_Tot_prev4_Bins)/Avg_Percent_of_Tot_prev4_Bins,4) AS PercentChg_Percent_of_Total

FROM Columns_qry2 
INNER JOIN Day_Period_bins_qry1 
ON Day_Period_bins_qry1.item =  Columns_qry2.Item

GROUP BY Columns_qry2.N_group, Columns_qry2.item, Columns_qry2.Day_period, Columns_qry2.nCount, Day_Period_bins_qry1.[7Day_Curnt];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a complete answer but one that needs testing and adjustment on your end, consider below re-formulation of your process. Specifically, consider keeping your data long by joining to a static lookup table of your needed `DateAdd` values, then join with date calculation, and aggregate with *Day_bin* added to grouping.

**Table**  *(myDateRangeTable)*

```
Start_Num  End_Num   Day_Period   Day_Bin
0          -6        '7Day'       'Curnt'     
-7         -13       '7Day'       '1'     
-14        -20       '7Day'       '2'     
-21        -27       '7Day'       '3'     
-28        -34       '7Day'       '4'     
0          -27       '28Day'      'Curnt'     
-28        -55       '28Day'      '1'     
-56        -83       '28Day'      '2'     
-84        -111      '28Day'      '3'     
-112       -139      '28Day'      '4'     
0          -83       '84Day'      'Curnt'     
-84        -167      '84Day'      '1'     
-168       -251      '84Day'      '2'     
-252       -335      '84Day'      '3'     
-336       -419      '84Day'      '4'     
0          -363      '364Day'     'Curnt'     
-364       -727      '364Day'     '1'     
-728       -1091     '364Day'     '2'     
-1092      -1455     '364Day'     '3'     
-1456      -1819     '364Day'     '4'
```

**Base Query 1**

Below cross joins above with original data table to pair match every combination of data table row with above selections. Then, counts any matches of date range. If original table is very large below may take some time to process. Consider [making it a temp table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b) if that is the case by adding an `INTO [myTempTable]` just before `FROM`. Below should replicate your union query.

```sql
SELECT 'Category' as N_group, 
        d.Item_Category as Item, 
        m.Day_Period,
        m.Day_Bin,
        SUM(d.[occ_date] BETWEEN DateAdd("d", m.Start_Num, [Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt]) 
                             AND DateAdd("d", m.End_Num, [Forms]![Main_frm]![Date_prompt_txt])
           ) AS Date_Count
FROM Data_tbl d,
     myDateRangeTable m
GROUP BY d.Item_Category,
         m.Day_Period,
         m.Day_Bin;
```

**Final Query** *(myFinalQuery)*

Below is an incomplete query, combining unit level and aggregate levels by *Day_Period*. Consider adjusting for needed formulas. The remaining challenges are to calculate fields across rows for different `Day_Bin` counts. This can require a nested `IIF` expression or join to a [crosstab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8). Note parentheses are required with multiple joins in MS Access' SQL dialect.

```sql
SELECT
  b.N_Group,
  b.Item,
  b.Day_Period,
  b.Day_Bin,
  Round((b.[Day_Count] - agg1.[Avg_Prev4_Bins]) / agg1.Std_Prev4_Bins, 2) 
       AS Z_score, 
  Round((b.[Day_Count] - agg1.[Avg_Prev4_Bins])) / b.[Day_Count], 2) 
       AS PercentChg_From_BinAvg_Prev4Bins, 
  Round(IIF(b.Day_Bin = 'Current', b.[Day_Count] / agg2.curr_SumDayCount,
            IIF(b.Day_Bin = '1',  b.[Day_Count] / agg2.d1_SumDayCount,
                IIF(b.Day_Bin = '2',  b.[Day_Count] / agg2.d2_SumDayCount, 
                    IIF(b.Day_Bin = '3',  b.[Day_Count] / agg2.d3_SumDayCount,
                        IIF(b.Day_Bin = '4',  b.[Day_Count] / agg2.d4_SumDayCount, NULL)
                        )
                   )
               )
           ), 
       2) AS Percent_of_Total, 
  ...
FROM
 ((myBaseQuery AS b
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Day_Period, 
             AVG(Day_Count) AS Avg_Prev4_Bins,
             StDevP([Day_Count]) AS Std_Prev4_Bins
      FROM myBaseQuery 
      GROUP BY Day_Period) AS agg1
   ON agg1.Day_Period = b.Day_Period)

INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Day_Period, 
             SUM(IIF(Day_Bin = 'Current', Day_Count, NULL)) AS curr_SumDayCount, 
             SUM(IIF(Day_Bin = '1', Day_Count, NULL)) AS d1_SumDayCount,
             SUM(IIF(Day_Bin = '2', Day_Count, NULL)) AS d2_SumDayCount,
             SUM(IIF(Day_Bin = '3', Day_Count, NULL)) AS d3_SumDayCount,
             SUM(IIF(Day_Bin = '4', Day_Count, NULL)) AS d4_SumDayCount  
      FROM myBaseQuery 
      GROUP BY Day_Period) AS agg2
   ON agg2.Day_Period = b.Day_Period)
```

**Crosstab Query**

Below is example of crosstab to be used as needed for unit level counts on same row to be joined to above and then have pivoted columns included in formulas with aggregate counterparts.

```sql
TRANSFORM SUM(Day_Count) AS SumDayCount
SELECT Day_Period
FROM myBaseQuery
GROUP BY Day_Period
PIVOT Day_Bin IN ([Curnt], [1], [2], [3], [4])
```

Hopefully some part of above is helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @Parfait. The static LU table will be especially helpful if the ranges need adjusted in the future. I will begin messing around with your suggestions.

Comment: So far, your base query has essentially accomplished what my first two queries attempt to accomplish, but 100x less cumbersome. The only missing pieces were the need of the absolute value for the sum function and two union queries for item_type and item_description.

Comment: The final error is throwing a syntax error in the from clause in `INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Day_Period, AVG(Day_Count) AS Avg_Prev4_Bins,
                         StDevP([Day_Count]),2) AS Std_Prev4_Bins
      FROM myBaseQuery 
      GROUP BY Day_Period) agg1
   ON agg.Day_Period = b.Day_Period)` Also, is the join criteria `ON agg.Day_Period = b.Day_Period)` supposed to be agg1.Day_period?

Comment: Good to hear this helped streamline your initial setup! Yes, you are correct. In fact, both `ON` clauses should be fixed. See edit. Once again last query will need additional modifications possibly with another `JOIN` for other columns.

Comment: Applied the edits. However, still getting a syntax error in a from clause and cannot get it resolved. Could it be that the error is being mis-identified? Although, I cannot find any other potential causes.

Comment: I think I got the parenthesis have been cleared up. Currently,  It returns an error that the z_score select statement is not part of an aggregate function. I am terrible at resolving these issues. Also, am I assuming correctly that Day_count is supposed to be the date_count column that was created in the first query?

Comment: Try again. I used `AVG` in outer query for *PercentChg_From_BinAvg_Prev4Bins*. If you are adjusting, you must use `GROUP BY` if using aggregates like `AVG`, and `StDevP`.

Comment: The final query is running. Now I am attempting to get the calculations, other than percent of total, to run only within their group. For example, a 7 Day z-score for an item type  based off the avg of the previous 4 7day groups and the deviation of the previous 4 7day groups for a given item. My first, naïve/wishful, attempt to resolve this issue was to simply include the item column in the select clause of `INNER JOIN (SELECT Day_Period, Offense, AVG(N_count) AS Avg_Prev4_Bins,
StDevP([N_count]) AS Std_Prev4_Bins`, but that resulted in accurate results and repeat records.

Comment: from what I have come across in my research, `partition by` would likely be the solution to my problem. Since it is not supported by Access I am going to attempt to accomplish this part of the project in SQL Server. Thank you for your help